# Closest number in array, but on Monopoly table

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a monopoly game in progress and I need to retrieve the closest location from given value. I get available closest locations like this:

```
function Field_GetNearestByCategory($current,$category) {
    $current = (int)$current;
    $category = SQLEscape($category);
    $s = "SELECT ID,Location FROM `card` WHERE Category='$category' AND Location <> $current";
    $qr = SQLQuery($s);
    $locs = array();
    while($r = SQLGetArray($qr)) {
        $locs[] = $r[1];
    }
    return $locs;
}
```

I have found solution for getting the closest value in array but problem occurs when $current == 40 and next closest field should be 6 (lets say we want to go to closest railroads).

```
function closest($search, $arr)
{
    $closest = null;
    foreach($arr as $item)
    {
        if($closest == null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search))
        {
            $closest = $item;
        }
    }
    return $closest;
}
```

Please note that if $current == 40, anything below it is FAR away since Monopoly goes in one direction so 1 is closer to 40 than 39.

**UPDATE:**

I have found solution, thanks everyone

```
function closest($search, $arr) {
    $c = null;
    sort($arr);
    foreach($arr as $k) {
        if($k > $search) { return $k; }
        else {
            if(!$c) $c = $k;
        }
    }
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: so in this example, you are calling the "closest" function with $search=40 and $arr=(6,16,26,36) and you want it to return 6?

Comment: It is an dynamic array but yes, in this example, I want to return 6. In case I have $search=35, next would be 36. if $search=37, next is 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a query that adds a "distance" field (the distance ahead the square is from $current) - mysql syntax for the CASE statement

```
SELECT ID, Location, 
CASE WHEN Location < $current THEN Location + 40 - $current 
    ELSE Location - $current
END
AS Distance 
FROM `card` WHERE Category='$category' AND Location <> $current
```

Comment: It throws sql error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS Distance FROM `card` WHERE Category='street' AND Location <> 40' at line 4

Comment: Oops I forgot END CASE :-/  Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry I'm not expert in MySQL so I had no idea about that. However, END CASE gives error "near 'CASE AS Distance'. I changed END CASE to END and now it has no error, is it valid syntax?

Comment: print_r($locs); returns Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 16 [2] => 26 [3] => 36 ) which is same as it was in my old query.

Comment: Yes it should be END.  Duh, bed time.  Anyway it won't affect the Location field (aka $r[1]) but the Distance field ($r[2]) is how far ahead of the current square it is.  If you only want the closest square, you can add "ORDER BY Distance ASC LIMIT 0,1" at the bottom.